# Редирект ссылок сайта

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс

Хочу поменять все человеко-понятные ссылки сайта с символьных на числовые, но в всех источниках (*ВК*, *Фейсбук* и т.д.) ссылки на сайт символьные.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при переходе по символьной ссылке `http://mysite.ru/catalog/tovar/oborudovanie/` автоматически перенаправляло на её числовой аналог: `http://mysite.ru/catalog/10/15/`?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте делать редирект средствами php. Алгоритм такой: пользователь попадает по чпу на страницу карточки товара, в компоненте берутся id товара и id его раздела, формируется url, посылается заголовок на редирект.

Comment: php можно, но сложно) По идее нужно задать прописать правило обработки адресов, не пойму только какое должно быть правило

Comment: никакое. из htaccess вы не получите информацию об id по символьному коду - там ее неоткуда взять.